# How to read this symbol, a', in English?

Tags: vocabulary, reading-aloud

While reading a English Syntax book, I wondered how I have to read a', a'', a''' in English.
Would you tell me how to?

Comment: I think most of us would like to see the context first. They might be pronounced _a prime, a double prime_, and _a triple prime_ respectively, but that might not always be the answer.

Comment: McCawley's *Syntactic Phenomena of English* uses ***A, P, V*** for *Adjective, Verb, Preposition*, and ***A', P', V'*** for *Adjective phrase, Verb phrase, Preposition phrase*. It doesn't use the double- or triple-tick versions though, so I just think of them as *A-tick*, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers McCawley says somewhere (a footnote to Ch. 1?) that ***A′, P′, ... X′*** were originally notated with a bar over the character, ***Ā***, &c, and that when the notation with the prime symbol was adopted for easier typesetting the expressions continued to be read ***A-bar, P-bar***, &c. Hence [X-bar theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-bar_theory).

Comment: @StoneyB: I found it in my copy by looking up *X-bar syntax* in the index, which led me to the discussion in Ch7 footnote 7. McCawley says that in *his* approach "multiple bars make no sense" in respect of A,P,V - but as you say, he does use them when "numbering" his example usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes - because lower-case a, b, c are not in his usage symbols of constituents, and the ticks are not 'bars'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are referring to McCawley's numbering system for example sentences:

(1) a.
   a′.
   a″.
   a‴.
   b. 
... and so forth.

These are not actually English words but typographic symbols. Like the tree diagrams, they're not really intended to be spoken.

If you have to speak them, you may as J.R. suggests say *a-prime*, *a-double-prime*, etc. (which is a use borrowed from mathematics), or you may as FumbleFingers suggests say *a-tick*, etc. (but that is a British rather than US usage).

Comment: I'm British and I've never heard "a-tick". In mathematics, it would be either "prime" or "dash". (No, I don't know why "dash", when a dash is a completely different piece of punctuation.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm most familiar with it in mathematics, where they are used as related designations of a variable a (or more commonly x, y, or z). I have always read them *a-prime*, *a-double-prime*. Haven't really come across a‴ before, but *a-triple-prime* makes sense.  Wikipedia begins with this entry for [**Prime (symbol)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)):

> The prime symbol ( ′ ), double prime symbol ( ″ ), and triple prime
>   symbol ( ‴ ), etc., are used to designate several different units and
>   for various other purposes in mathematics, the sciences, linguistics
>   and music.